# how to remove duplicate entry from the text file using batch script or vb script?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

how can I remove the duplicate entry from the text file using batch script. All i want to remove the duplicates before "=" sign and "%%" is exist in every single text file. Text file look likes below

```
%%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_IBDE_UNC=\\%%B05AIPS_UPLOAD_NODE.\F$\DATA\IPSL\CDFILES\B05_NAG\CD\INCOMING
%%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC=\\%%B05AIPS_UPLOAD_NODE.\B05_NAG\FTS\To_Clearpath\%%DATE_CCYYMMDD. 
%%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC=%%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC.
```

I got about 30 plus different text files which contains above kind of entries and want to remove the duplicate line and want to keep the first occurrence. Remember duplicate line should be identified before "=" sign only and removal required for the entire line.Each of the different text files have got "%%" sign. Please guide me if there is way to do through batch *script* or *vbscript*? Thanks

Comment: What is duplicate -- the entire line, or only a portion?

Comment: Duplicate is not entire line just the value before equal to sign  i.e. %%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC. But I want to remove the whole line of first occurance not the second occurance.

Comment: Do these strings always start with `%%`?

Comment: yes the strings always start with %%

Comment: So [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36475474) providing a pure [tag:batch-file] solution should work for a single file -- check it out and let me know; you are talking about multiple files in your question, but it is not clear if the tokens left to the `=` sign need to be unique per each file individually, or per the entire collection of files; so please clarify that by updating your post; also the information the left part of `=` and the `%%` prefix should be mentioned in the question rather than in comments only...

Comment: aschipfl I have updated my question. please check and let me know the correct answer. For more clarification I can say in above text file %%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC before "=" sign is duplicate entry . So I want to remove the entire line of first occurance which is %%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC=\\%%B05AIPS_UPLOAD_NODE.\B05_NAG\FTS\To_Clearpath\%%DATE_CCYYMMDD not the second occurance.

Comment: Answer your question tokens left to the = sign need to be unique per each file individually. So it should be unique for all the multiple files i.e for 30-35 files.

Comment: 1. In the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36424679) you said you want to *keep* the first occurrence in case of duplicates, but in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424679/how-to-remove-duplicate-entry-from-the-text-file-using-batch-script-or-vb-script#comment60848678_36424679) you say to *remove* the first occurrence, so what do you want now? 2. Do you want to check for duplicates in a case-sensitive or case-insensitive manner?

Comment: Sorry for confusion aschipfl. My requirement is I want to remove the first occurrence only not the second occurrence in case of duplicates. I want to check for duplicates in a case-insensitive manner. Hope you get your answer now. Please also let me know if you have a solution in a VB script as well.

Comment: Okay... please edit your question, put all the extra information from your comments there, and correct the statement about which line to keep in case of duplicates (you want to keep the *last* one rather than the *first* one); thanks... I have no VBScript solution (at the moment), but I have edited my answer yesterday, providing **improved scripts** of which I think the second one is suitable for your (updated and clarified) requirements...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution; let us call the script `rem-dups.bat`. Supposing your input file is `test.txt` and your output file is `result.txt`, you need to provide these files as command line arguments, so you need to call it by: `rem-dups.bat "test.txt" "results.txt"`. Here is the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "INFILE=%~1"
set "OUTFILE=%~2"
if not defined INFILE exit /B 1
if not defined OUTFILE set "OUTFILE=con"

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims==" %%K in ("%INFILE%") do (
    set "LEFT=%%K"
    set "RIGHT=%%L"
    set "LEFT=!LEFT:*%%%%=__!"
    rem Remove `if` query to keep last occurrence:
    if not defined !LEFT! set "!LEFT!=!RIGHT!"
)
> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('set __') do (
        set "LINE=%%F"
        echo(!LINE:*__=%%%%!
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The script is based on the fact that there cannot occur duplicate environment variables, that are such with equal names.

This code only works if the following conditions are fulfilled:

- the file content is treated in a case-insensitive manner;
- the order of lines in the output file does not matter;
- the partial strings before the first `=` sign start with `%%` and contain at least one more character other than `%`;
- the partial strings before the first `=` contain only characters which may occur within environment variable names, besides the leading `%%`;
- the partial strings after the first `=` must not be empty;
- the partial strings after the first `=` must not start with `=` on their own;
- no exclamation marks `!` are allowed within the file, because they may get lost or lead to other unexpected results;

---

Here is an alternative method using a temporary file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "INFILE=%~1"
set "OUTFILE=%~2"
if not defined INFILE exit /B 1
if not defined OUTFILE set "OUTFILE=con"
set "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

> "%TEMPFILE%" break
> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INFILE%") do (
        for /F tokens^=1^,*^ delims^=^=^ eol^= %%E in ("%%L") do (
            > nul 2>&1 findstr /I /X /L /C:"%%E" "%TEMPFILE%" || (
                echo(%%L
                >> "%TEMPFILE%" echo(%%E
            )
        )
    )
)
> nul 2>&1 del "%TEMPFILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Every unique (non-empty) token left to the first `=` sign is written to a temporary file, which is searched after having read each line from the input file. If the token is already available in the temporary file, the line is skipped; if not, it is written to the output file.

The file content is treated in a case-insensitive manner, unless you remove the `/I` switch from the `findstr` command.

---

#### Update: Improved Scripts

Here are two scripts which are improved so that no special character can bring them to fail. They do not use temporary files. Both scripts remove lines with duplicate keywords (such is the partial string before the first `=` sign).

This script keeps the *first* line in case of duplicate keywords have been encountered:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "INFILE=%~1"
set "OUTFILE=%~2"
if not defined INFILE exit /B 1
if not defined OUTFILE exit /B 1

> "%OUTFILE%" break
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INFILE%") do (
    for /F tokens^=1^ delims^=^=^ eol^= %%E in ("%%L") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        set "KEY=%%E"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if not "!LINE:~,1!"=="=" (
            set "KEY=!KEY:  = !"
            set "KEY=!KEY:\=\\!" & set "KEY=!KEY:"=\"!"
            more /T1 "%OUTFILE%" | > nul 2>&1 findstr /I /M /B /L /C:"!KEY!=" || (
                >> "%OUTFILE%" echo(!LINE!
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script keeps the *last* line in case of duplicate keywords have been encountered:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "INFILE=%~1"
set "OUTFILE=%~2"
if not defined INFILE exit /B 1
if not defined OUTFILE exit /B 1

> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%INFILE%"') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("%%L") do set "LNUM=%%N"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
        if defined LINE if not "!LINE:~,1!"=="=" (
            for /F tokens^=1^ delims^=^=^ eol^= %%E in ("!LINE!") do (
                setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
                set "KEY=%%E"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                set "KEY=!KEY:  = !"
                set "KEY=!KEY:\=\\!" & set "KEY=!KEY:"=\"!"
                more /T1 +!LNUM! "%INFILE%" | > nul 2>&1 findstr /I /M /B /L /C:"!KEY!=" || (
                    echo(!LINE!
                )
                endlocal
                endlocal
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

For both scripts, the following rules apply:

- the order of lines with non-duplicate keywords is maintained;
- empty lines are ignored and therefore removed;
- empty keywords, meaning lines starting with `=`, are ignored and therefore removed;
- non-empty lines that do not contain an `=` at all are treated as they would be ended with an `=` for the check for duplicates, hence the entire line is used as the keyword;
- for the check for duplicates, each <kbd>TAB</kbd> character is replaced by a single <kbd>SPACE</kbd>;
- every line that is transferred to the returned file is copied from the original file without changes (hence the aforementioned attachment of `=` or replacement of <kbd>TAB</kbd> is not reflected there);
- the check for duplicates is done in a case-insensitive manner, unless you remove the `/I` switch from the `findstr` command;

---

#### Amendment: Processing Multiple Files

All of the above scripts are designed for processing a single file only. However, if you need to process multiple files, you could simply write a wrapper that contains a `for` loop enumerating all the input files and calls one of the scripts above (called `rem-dups.bat`) for every item -- like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "INPATH=D:\Data\source"  & rem (location of input files)
set "OUTPATH=D:\Data\target" & rem (location of output files)
set INFILES="source.txt" "test*.txt" & rem (one or more input files)
set "OUTSUFF=_no-dups" & rem (optional suffix for output file names)
set "SUBBAT=%~dp0rem-dups.bat"

pushd "%INPATH%" || exit /B 1
for %%I in (%INFILES%) do if exist "%%~fI" (
    call "%SUBBAT%" "%%~fI" "%OUTPATH%\%%~nI%OUTSUFF%%%~xI"
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

You must not specify the same locations for the input and output files. If you want to overwrite the original input files, you need to write the modified output files to another location first, then you can move them back to the source location -- supposing you have set `OUTSUFF` in the wrapper script to an empty string (`set "OUTSUFF="` instead of `set "OUTSUFF=_no-dups"`). The command line to overwrite the original input files would be: `move /Y "D:\Data\target\*.*" "D:\Data\source"`.

Comment: HI aschipfl, Thanks for your script. It works OK with single file but it not working with wild character i.e. *.txt see below how I try to do                    FOR /F %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "*.txt"') do (  . its not working if I change from test.txt to *.txt. And I want to remove duplicates from about more than 30 txt files. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: The scripts are designed for processing a single file only; meanwhile I changed to scripts so that the input and output files are no longer constants but need to be delivered as command line arguments; in addition, I appended and amendment illustrating how to deal with multiple files; see my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36475474/10)...

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file into Excel without splitting it into multiple columns. Use Excel functionality to eliminate duplicates and save it back. You could do all this in VBScript.

```
Create an Excel Object
Loop
    Load text file
    Remove duplicates
    Save text file
Until there are no more files
Dispose of the Excel Object
```

Code for the individual pieces should be easily available on the web. Do ask for any additional, specific, pointers you might need.

Comment: Thanks MikeC . But please can you give the entire vbscript command line to execute. Remember duplicate is just the value before equal to sign i.e. %%B05AIPS_CDDOWNLOAD_FTS_UNC not the entire line. But removal required for entire line of first occurance not the second occurance. Also please tell me the website link where I can find as you mentioned on your reply.

Comment: The philosophy of SO is that people try to write their own code and ask for help with specific problems they're facing. People post the code they're having problem with. All of this is encapsulated in the frequently stated "SO is not a code writing service." Please also look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)